# (Edited) MSVC++ Shortcut to define array in stack frame

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++14

Is there a shortcut (e.g. MACRO/templates) to define char stack arrays with macros?

I need a *char by char* definition to force the MS compiler constructing the array in place into the stack frame. This is needed for shellcoding purpose, avoiding to manually write each string char by char.

E.g. using macros

```
#define MACRO(arr, s) ...

int main()
{
    MACRO(arr, thisisasuperlongstring);
}
```

to obtain

```
int main()
{
    char arr[] = {'t','h','i','s','i','s','a','s','u','p','e','r','l','o','n','g','s','t','r','i','n','g',0};
}
```

Comment: Simply defining an array may work, but I don't think you can specify how compilers should express the strings internally in a standard way. https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/316cqTar6

Comment: What would this accomplish that `char arr[] = "thisisasuperlongstring";` wouldn't?

Comment: You do it like that: `char arr[] = "thisisasuperlongstring";` with no macros.

Comment: This is useful in PIC where you need to allocate the string in place onto the stack frame. In your case "thisisasuperlongstring" will be placed by the compiler into another image section.

Comment: @wmi: "*I'd like to avoid leaving strings into .rdata section*" It will still be in your executable somewhere as an array of characters. If you're trying to hide some text, this isn't particularly effective at it.

Comment: The compiler will treat it the same way whether you initialized the array with `= "..."` or with `= {...}`.

Comment: *In your case "thisisasuperlongstring" will be placed by the compiler into another image section* This appears to be false.

Comment: You might want to use `#pragma section` instead.

Comment: @prapin with `#pragma section  (".text")` and `__declspec(allocate(".text")) char arr[] = "...";` I figured out to force **arr** into the **.text**. But the resulting code references a fixed address (subject to relocation) and it isn't that suitable for PIC

Comment: @interjay not so true :)

Comment: @wmi My compiler says it's exactly the same. Do you have any evidence to the contrary?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible:

```cpp
#define STRINGIFY_HELPER(A) #A
#define STRINGIFY(A) STRINGIFY_HELPER(A)

#define MAGIC_MACRO(arr, content) char arr[] = STRINGIFY(content)
```

https://godbolt.org/z/MvoEa77KG

but should be avoided if possible (provide more context if you wish to get better answer).

Comment: Thanks, but this approach is equivalento to `char arr[]="thisisasuperlongstring";`. I'd like to define the array in place into the stack, writing position independent code.

Comment: And this does exactly same result as `char arr[] = {'t','h','i','s','i','s','a','s','u','p','e','r','l','o','n','g','s','t','r','i','n','g',0};` so what is your point?

Comment: If you try to compile with Microsoft **cl**, the first assignment puts a string into the **.rdata** section, while the second one fills the array in place onto the stack **arr[0]** to **arr[n-1]**. My point is to find a shortcut instead of writing char by char by hand

Comment: @interjay maybe you can refer to this one

Comment: @wmi please edit your question (or create new one) and focus on your actual problem not how to fix your solution. Remember to put this variable in some context (function, global scope) since this has great impact what optimizer will do. Note that differences are not important: https://godbolt.org/z/xro6qrWzP